# append data frame to existing worksheet for particular column by pandas or openpy excel

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

Append data frame to existing workbook for particular column

[1 table is excel work book](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eEPrd.png)

[2 nd table is data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aBGTf.png)

[output should be like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqRmz.png)

Comment: Please rework your question to be easily readable without clicking links.

Comment: hi, how to append data frame with excel sheet for particular column

Answer (score 0):

first read excel files using `pd.read_excel(file path)`, then use:

```
df.append(df2)
```

Illustration:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'code':[1,2], 'name': ['a', 'b'], 'class':[5,9], 'rol': ['y', 'h'], 'sub':['eng', 'math']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': ['c', 'd'], 'class':[5,9], 'rol': ['y', 'h']})
df.append(df2)
```

Output:

```
    code    name    class   rol sub
0   1.0 a   5   y   eng
1   2.0 b   9   h   math
0   NaN c   5   y   NaN
1   NaN d   9   h   NaN
```

Comment: excel sheet is formulated, so cant take as data frame

Comment: can you upload sample excel files?

Comment: mypath="C:\\Users\\egoyrat\\Desktop\\smt tracker\\Swap Manual Tracking_v1 (12).xlsx"
wb = load_workbook(mypath,read_only=False)
wb_ws= wb['Main']
for row in dataframe_to_rows(now_append, header = False, index = False):
        wb_ws.append(row)
wb.save(mypath)  # save workbook
wb.close()

Comment: i use this, data is appending but, not for particular column

Comment: I need your sample excel files. Please upload them if you want a solution.

Comment: where to upload

Comment: There are plenty of sites for this such as this https://uupload.ir/.